# C# How open form in another panel

Tags: c#

not work  correct like nothing happened when do it

```
private void DGV_Pat_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           PL.History.Frm_History Frm = new History.Frm_History()
            {
                TopLevel = false
            };
           PL.MainPage.Frm_Main Main = new MainPage.Frm_Main();
            if (Main.Pnl_Main.Controls.Count > 0)
                Main.Pnl_Main.Controls.Clear();
            Main.Pnl_Main.Controls.Add(Frm);
            Frm.BringToFront();
            Frm.Show();
}
```

i try to open form by clicking on form  and open new form in another panel form

Comment: You added `Frm` to `Main`, but never displayed or added `Main` to anything...

Comment: Please do not tag your IDE if your question is not about your IDE. The fact that you develop your code using Visual Studio Code doesn't make a difference to the problem or its solution. You could equally develop your code in Visual Studio (as opposed to the Visual Studio Code application), Rider, MonoDevelop, Notepad, Vim, etc. and experience the exact same problem.

Comment: It also appears that you keep tagging specific versions of C# (C# 2, C# 3, C# 4, etc.) even though it's clear your question can't be about code compiled against all of these simultaneously. Should we assume the lowest common denominator (C# 2, released in November 2005) and ignore any improvements to the C# language in the 17+ years since? Doing so might hinder us from giving you relevant answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed it by using this code

```
 private void DGV_Pat_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Panel p = this.Parent as Panel;
            if (p != null)
            {
                PL.History.Frm_History Frm = new History.Frm_History()
                {
                    TopLevel = false
                };
                p.Controls.Add(Frm);
                Frm.BringToFront();
                Frm.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```